# Constructing representation of $G$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory

Say we are given an arbitrary group $G$ and an arbitrary vector space $V$ over some field.

> How can we construct a representation of $G$ on some vector space from this data?

Initially I wanted to consider $G\times V$ a vector space with addition/scalar multiplication $(g_1,v_1)+\alpha (g_2,v_2)=(g_1g_2,v_1+\alpha v_2)$ and then define a representation by

$$\rho:G\to GL(G\times V)\\ \rho(g)=\left((h,v)\mapsto (gh,v) \right)$$

but it was pointed out to me that $G\times V$ is not a vector space in general (e.g. when $G$ is not abelian).

Comment: Even if $\;G\;$ is abelian that cartesian product won't be a linear space over arbitrary fields in general.

Answer (score 0):

You want to construct a homomorphism $G \to GL(V)$: normally the easiest way of doing this is to choose a presentation for $G$ as $G = \langle X | R \rangle$, and choose matrices in $GL(V)$ to map the generators $x_i \in X$ to such that the relators $R$ are all satisfied.

A simple example is $V = \mathbb R^2$ and $G = \langle x | x^5\rangle = C_5$, then we can choose $$x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi/5) & \sin(2\pi/5) \\ -\sin(2\pi/5) & \cos(2\pi/5) \end{pmatrix}$$

(This all assumes that $G$ is finitely presented.)

You also always have the "regular representation" of $G$: take a vector space with basis $e_g$, and define the representation by sending $g$ to the linear map $\phi_g: e_h \mapsto e_{gh}$. This completely ignores your vector space $V$, however! I'm not aware of any method of constructing a non-trivial representation of $G$ on $V$ algorithmically for arbitrary $G$ and $V$.

Comment: Well, the actually easiest way is to send everything to the identity.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment before editing - as you say, that is definitely the easiest way! Though I don't know whether or not the OP wanted a non-trivial representation.

Comment: The OP is not guaranteed that there are any non-trivial ones (as can be seen by taking for example the group $A_5$ and a complex vector space of dimension $2$).

Comment: I don't necessarily want a group homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$. Just a group homomorphism $G\to GL(W)$ for some vector space $W$ which should somehow involve $V$ and $G$.

Comment: In genral this is the only thing you can do. For every $n$ there is a group $G$ whose irreducible complex representations are, apart from the trivial one, of dimension larger than $n$ (for example, the alternating group of degree $n$ has minimal nontrivial degree qual to $n-1$)

Comment: @JohnSteinbeck in that case Tobias' answer is a good one: take the trivial representation.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt So the trivial one is $G\to GL(V), g\mapsto id_V$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.